# Write what I say in a TextView

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I created a `Button` to start the `RecognizeActivity`

```
 private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Demo Speech");
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_REC_CODE);
        }
```

Where `VOICE_REC_CODE` is `private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;`.

I would display what I have said in a `TextView` when I tap the `Button`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may use `Google Speech API`. Please take a look here https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160

You should make a POST request to https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize with a FLAC formatted voice binary in a body of request. Then you'll get a `JSON` with recognized text that can be pasted into your `TextView`.

Comment: I'll take a look..it seems pretty complicated. Is there an easier way?